# implementation of a vector with all but one read only entries

Tags: c++, class, vector, operator-overloading

I want to basically implement a vector that allows to write to only one entry that is passed to it at the time of construction. Something like this :

```
// create a vector v of size s where only v[my_index] is writable
myVector <T> v (s, my_index); 
// read of any index is allowed, so following succeeds for any index
std::cout << v [index] << std::endl;
// if index is not equal to my_index, following generates an error
// preferably at compile time
v [index] = t;
```

My belief at this point is that this is impossible to implement. I searched a bit online and could come up with the following implementation of myVector that uses constant references in a clever way, but does not allow write-access to any element whatsoever.

```
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
class myVector {
  int my_index;
  vector <T> _v;
public:
  const vector <T> &v;
  myVector (int size, int _my_index);
  const T* operator [] (int index);
};

template <class T>
myVector<T>::myVector (int size, int _my_index) : v(_v) {
  my_index = _my_index;
  _v.resize (size);
}

template <class T>
const T* myVector<T>::operator [] (int index) {
  return &v[index];
}
```

Is there way to achieve this? The whole motivation for this is to be able to have a nice access interface for the vector, so suggestions like using getter-setter functions etc. are not welcome.

Comment: is it acceptable for `my_index` to be a template parameter? if so this would be a bit easier I think. edit: also, if you want the error to be "preferably at compile time" then that is necessary. it might help the question also if you give some motivation for why you want this data structure, it doesn't sound particularly useful.

Comment: Other than template option, the only other way I can think of is to return a proxy object a la `vector<bool>` that throws if you modify the value for a non-writable index.

Comment: You may think you want to do this, but you don't want to do this.  An interface that allows you to call setters for any index you like, except it generates an error unless you use that special index that was passed to it at construction time, which you can't know about unless it was also passed to you through another channel...  is crazy.

Comment: It is not clear to me how to do it using a template or proxy object. Can you please answer how to implement using these? The use case is that there are multiple nodes each owning one row of a table. A node is allowed to modify its own row, but can read other rows via RDMA. I just wanted to have a clean representation like this. It won't lead to any confusion, because the row that is writable to a node is the one that it owns.

Answer (score 0):

Either name the accesor and mutator different things, such as `v[i]` and `v.set(x)`, or have the non-const `operator[]` return `end()` for any but the magic number and make clients access the vector through a `const&` or `const_cast` to read any other elements.  A template argument will not work if you pass in anything but a compile-time integral constant as an argument.